# ¿Como abrir un modal desde el controlador de Symfony?

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

> Tratando de solventar una duda me encontré con otra, se puede abrir un
> modal desde el return de una función en symfony?

**1. Mi botón**

```
   <a class="btn btn-outline-danger" style="font-size: 16px;" href="{{ path('app_usuario_eliminar', {'id': r.id}) }}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>Eliminar</a>
   {% include '/usuario/modal_eliminar.html.twig' %}
```

**2. Mi función**

```
   #[Route('/eliminar', name: 'app_usuario_eliminar')]
   public function eliminar(ManagerRegistry $doctrine, Request $request): Response
   {
     $param =$request->get('id');

      return $this->render('usuario/modal_eliminar.html.twig',
         [
            'param' =>$param,
         ]
      );
   }
```

**3. Lo que obtengo**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Existe una forma de hacer esto o es directamente imposible.

Comment: ahi lo que estas diciendo es que abra una pagina web, llamada "modal_eliminar.html.twig". Y eso es lo que estas viendo, un render de dicha pagina. Para lanzar un "modal", debes llamar a la pagina contenedora de dicho modal, con algun parametro tipo "lanzar=true", y en la plantilla modal_eliminar.html.twig analizar dicho parametro para que lance el javascript correspondiente del modal.

Comment: De todas formas, creo que lo que estas haciendo lo puedes simplificar un poco. tu controlador deberia unicamente hacer el borrado y volver a la plantilla general. Tu boton borrar es el que tiene que lanzar el emergente (probablemente sea un confirmar borrado, no?) y cuando pulses en ese confirmar, entonces llamas a la url  del controlador.